type '(int) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => void'
I checked all my generics are all OK. Inheritance seems ok. Type inference seems ok. No compiler error. I don't have any hard type casting. Everything is seems strongly typed.
class ModelField {}

class DropdownField<V> extends ModelField {
  final void Function(V value) setValue;

  final List<V> options;

  DropdownField({
    required this.setValue,
    required this.options,
  });
}

void _buildDropdownField<V>(DropdownField<V> field) {
  final options = field.options;
  final data = options.first;

  field.setValue(data); // error Here
}

void _renderField(ModelField field) {
  /// from server
  // if field is StringField, else if field is DateField, ... else
  if (field is DropdownField<Object>) {
    // print('field is DropdownField<dynamic, dynamic>');
    _buildDropdownField(field);
  }
}

void main() {
  final field =
      DropdownField<int>(setValue: (value) => print(value), options: [1, 2, 3]);

  _renderField(field);
}

But when I run:
Unhandled exception:
type '(int) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => void'
#0      _buildDropdownField (package:shared_core/weird_dart/generic_promotion.dart:18:9)
#1      _renderField (package:shared_core/weird_dart/generic_promotion.dart:26:5)
#2      main (package:shared_core/weird_dart/generic_promotion.dart:34:3)
#3      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#4      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

How can int not be a subtype of Object???
I am so confused (or Dart is) I hope it's me. But this error occurs only at run time.

While int is a subtype of Object, (int) => void is not a subtype (Object) => void. Because imagine this (int) => void doing something with the argument that only an int could do, this would give problems when called with a non-int object

It seems casting to a supertype makes setValue completely unusable in any way. Even doing print(field.setValue); instead of _buildDropdownField(field); will throw an error, while it goes fine if you check on is DropdownField<int> instead. I'm not sure if there is a way to simply check for DropdownField without getting error. You might need to check each individual expected subtype

The proper solution I found is  to give the compiler "more clues" about the  Sound Variance. Hence use the keyword inout Thus: class DropdownField<inout V> . What the inout keyword means

“Hey, compiler, V in DropdownField is gonna both take values
in and give them out. V is in when we pass it to setValue, and it’s
out when we get values from options. So don’t stress—it’s all good for
both directions!”

Note:
This still an experimental flag.
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.3 <4.0.0'

And add the experimental flag.  --enable-experiment=variance
class ModelField {}

class DropdownField<inout V> extends ModelField {
  final void Function(V value) setValue;

  final List<V> options;

  DropdownField({
    required this.setValue,
    required this.options,
  });
}

void _buildDropdownField<V>(DropdownField<V> field) {
  final options = field.options;
  final data = options.first;

  print(field.setValue);
  field.setValue(data);
}

void _renderField(ModelField field) {
  /// from server
  // if field is StringField, else if field is DateField, ... else
  if (field is DropdownField<Object>) {
    // print('field is DropdownField<dynamic, dynamic>');
    _buildDropdownField(field);
  }
}

void main() {
  final field =
  DropdownField<int>(setValue: (value) => print(value), options: [1, 2, 3]);

  _renderField(field);
}


After you call this:
    final field = DropdownField<int>(
                    setValue: (value) => print(value), options: [1, 2,3],
                  );
    _renderField(field);
...

I think the main problem here is this:
void _renderField(ModelField field) {
  if (field is DropdownField<Object>) {
    _buildDropdownField(field);
  }
...

Because after this your type is not int but Object. From where you got

type '(int) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => void'

which is obvious: first function is not subtype of the second.
So, you should check your exact type here:
void _renderField(ModelField field) {
  if (field is DropdownField<int>) {
    _buildDropdownField(field);
  }

  if (field is DropdownField<String>) {
    _buildDropdownField(field);
  }
...
enter code here

Take a look here

but this ruins the idea of polymorphism. It hardcodes by assuming that we know all the possible types of V, which is not the case. V can be anything, int, bool, custom enum, custom class, Foo, Bar, DateTime,...

Not sure if there is a better way to do it, but a workaround is to add this method to your DropdownField class
  void callSetValue(dynamic value) {
    if (value is V) {
      setValue(value);
    }
  }

And then in _buildDropdownField instead of calling
field.setValue(data);

call
field.callSetValue(data);


You forgot to specify some generic stuff, and the compile is assuming Object? in each case. See in this sample what you didn't specify.
class ModelField {}

class DropdownField<V> extends ModelField {
  final void Function(V value) setValue;

  final List<V> options;

  DropdownField({
    required this.setValue,
    required this.options,
  });
}

void _buildDropdownField<V>(DropdownField<V> field) {
  final options = field.options;
  final data = options.first;

  field.setValue(data);
}

void renderField<V>(ModelField field) {
  if (field is DropdownField<V>) {
    _buildDropdownField(field);
  }
}

void main() {
  final field = DropdownField<int>(setValue: print, options: [1, 2, 3]);

  renderField<int>(field);
}

But, there are two other solutions to your problem:
Consolidating the functions into the class (and a single generic).
class ModelField {}

class DropdownField<V> extends ModelField {
  final void Function(V value) setValue;

  DropdownField({
    required this.setValue,
  });

  void renderField(Object data) {
    if (data is List<V>) {
      setValue(data.first);
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  final field = DropdownField<int>(setValue: print);

  field.renderField([1, 2, 3]);
}

Using a valid callback (not ideal in this case, Object is too broad).
class ModelField {}

class DropdownField<V> extends ModelField {
  final void Function(V value) setValue;

  final List<V> options;

  DropdownField({
    required this.setValue,
    required this.options,
  });
}

void _buildDropdownField<V>(DropdownField<V> field) {
  final options = field.options;
  final data = options.first;

  field.setValue(data); // error Here
}

void _renderField(ModelField field) {
  /// from server
  // if field is StringField, else if field is DateField, ... else
  if (field is DropdownField<Object>) {
    // print('field is DropdownField<dynamic, dynamic>');
    _buildDropdownField(field);
  }
}

void main() {
  // only `(Object value)` changes
  final field = DropdownField<int>(setValue: (Object value) => print(value), options: [1, 2, 3]);

  _renderField(field);
}

